# Why are my `addEventListen` buttons only working once?

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I have three functions all of which contain `contents.innerHTML = 'some HTML';`.

These functions are to rewrite the `innerHTML` of the div with an id of contents when called.

I also have three buttons on the nav bar which are specified at the top of each functions `innerHTML`. I.E the buttons themselves are also being rewritten along with the rest of the HTML when a function is called.

These buttons each have their own separate id and therefore they each have a `document.getElementById('button-id');` in the JS file.

I then use the following event to call each function:

```
buttonName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  functionCall();
});
```

My problem is that my buttons work only once. After I've clicked any of them once they do not work again. I feel like the reason is staring me in the face but I just can't see it.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <div id="content"></div>
</main>
```

JS:

```
const displayUser = () => {
  content.innerHTML = `
  <div class="nav-panel">
    <a class="nav-div-l nav-pic-bg hover"><img class="nav-pic-l nav-img" src="${img.arrows[2]}" alt="Logout Arrow">
    <h2 id="logout-btn">Back</h2></a>
    <a id="user-btn" class="nav-div-c hover"><img class="nav-pic-c nav-img" src="${img.user[0]}" alt="User Picture">
    <h2>Username</h2></a>
    <a id="settings-btn" class="nav-div-r hover hide-mobile"><h2>Settings</h2>
    <img class="nav-pic-r nav-img settings-img" src="${img.symbols[2]}" alt="Settings Cog"></a>
    <a class="settings-btn hide-desktop"><img class="nav-img" src="${img.symbols[2]}" alt="Settings Cog"></a>
  </div>

  --- MORE NON NAV RELATED HTML ---
  `;
};
```

All three functions look exactly the same as this in terms of the nav HTML.

```
displayLists(); // load page with displayLists

const logoutBtn = document.getElementById('logout-btn'); // nav links
const userBtn = document.getElementById('user-btn');
const settingsBtn = document.getElementById('settings-btn');

logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displayLists()
}); // change to lists page

userBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displayUser()
}); // change to user page

settingsBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  displaySettings()
}); // change to settings page
```

Comment: i guess that that events should be in displayUsers func.

Comment: FYI, you're passing extra functions unnecessarily. You can skip the arrow function, and do this:  `logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', displayLists);`